# Cache solution for a news feed, based on objective information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, caching, redis, memcached

I need some suggestions of what works well for caching an updatable news feed.

Please, no "Fanboy" answers either please - not looking for subjective opinions of what the "best" system, just seeking some suggestions of technologies that will fit the requirements below.  So please, share what you have used in the real world, even if you prefer some other solution.

I have a rails based news feed (Neo4j database), and while performance is good, I would like to cache it so that servers don't get bogged down serving live feeds.

REQUIREMENTS:

- EASY FRAGMENT UPDATES:  I'd like to easily update parts of a user's newsfeed the
  cache based upon specific triggers, for example, when a user edits
  their status update - I don't want to regenerate the user's entire
  news feed in the cache, rather I just want to update that one
  "fragment", or section if you will,  of the particular user's feed. And I don't want to jump through hoops to try and do so.
- DELETION: If someone deletes an activity, I just want to remove that activity
  from their news feed before the system eventually refreshes the entire feed for that user.
- EASY RETRIEVAL: I'd like to retrieve the cache in such a way that the rails
  controller/models can easily read them and hand them off to views without
  any modification of the views.
- PERSISTENCE:  If I need to reboot the cache, it should load up the
  cache from disk. Which means it should save cached entries to disk.
- SPEED:  Given that it must be able to be update fragments of cached
  news feeds, there is going to be a performance hit of some sort.  But
  I need speed..

What cache technologies provide such capabilities? Will Redis, MongoDB, Memcached fit these requirements?  What other options are there? (CouchDB, Tokyo File cabinet, etc)..

In the spirit Stack Overflow, I'm not asking for subjective opinions on what you like better and why, I'm just asking for possible candidate systems that you may have actually used in production to accomplish caching and updating a cached news feed (or anything similar).

Comment: How is MongoDB not persistent? Also "liking" something is subjective, for example I don't like rails but you clearly do. That's an opinion.

Comment: I said "AFAIK" = as far as I know.. Obviously I'm asking for people to chime in on what solutions would work and why, based upon experience and not just because they are a MongoDB, Redis, or whatever fan.

Comment: You shouldn't use short hand like that, I actually didn't know what AFAIK was, now I do. Not only that but short hand may mean different things across different regions, you should try using proper English. Anyway no matter how to phrase this you will get a fan boy answer.

Comment: Ok - I modified my questions. Do you have any suggestions as to what kinds of systems meet such requirements?

Comment: why do you need PERSISTENCE?  You say "If I need to reboot the cache, it should load up the cache from disk. Which means it should save cached entries to disk" but the whole advantage of having a cache is you don't need to persist it because you can rebuild it (in case of a crash, or whatever).  That's a *very* heavy-weight requirement you're putting on this, just to (prematurely?) optimize start-up time for rebuilding the cache it seems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is mainly an opinion-based topic, this answer will be subjective. But I will try anyway to remain factual.

The first point to notice is your requirements tend to be mutually exclusive. As we said in France, you want the butter, the money for the butter, and the wife of the farmer (ok, this is probably a lousy translation).

For example, to support easy fragment updates and proper deletion, you will need some kind of data structures in the cache. I have zero knowledge about Rails, but I guess it will have impact on the data access patterns, and the definitions of controllers/models. In other words, it will add complexity to data retrieval. You need speed, but at the same time, you also require persistency, and also non-trivial data access patterns. Well, you cannot get everything at the same time, you will have to make choices, and prioritize these requirements.

My second point is a cache is only useful when there is a significant difference in term of performance between the cache and the underlying storage engine. Since you already use a NoSQL engine which is rather efficient (Neo4j), you need to consider only engines which are truly designed for raw performance (i.e. low-latency stores): [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [redis](http://redis.io/), [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/), [aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/), to name well-established open-source products. If you feel a bit more adventurous, you can also consider other projects like [tarantool](http://tarantool.org/) or [hyperdex](http://hyperdex.org/).

There are a number of commercial products as well, but I'm not sure they provide a Ruby client (TIBCO ActiveSpaces, Gigaspaces, Red-Hat Infinispan, etc ...)

Other NoSQL engines (MongoDB, Cassandra, CouchDB, etc ...) have other interesting properties, but they will not beat these solutions at raw performance for a mixed r/w workload. Here, I'm only talking about raw performance (i.e. low latency at high throughput), not scalability.

Actually, memcached can be excluded because it does not support persistency.  I would say you can probably implement what you want with Redis, Couchbase or Aerospike, but Aerospike 3 does not seem to have yet an officially supported Ruby client.

Supporting multiple data accesses paths (i.e. consistent indexing data structure) will be easier with Redis and Aerospike than Couchbase. High-availability will be easier with Couchbase or Aerospike than with Redis. Implementing a cache behavior will be easier with Redis and Couchbase than with Aerospike.

Some general advices:

- make sure you really have a performance or a scalability issue with Neo4j before adding the complexity of an extra layer. Complexity is like toothpaste: once it is out of the tube, you cannot put it back.
- data access patterns should be listed at design time, and must be backed by corresponding data structures in the chosen engine.
- the hardware footprint must be considered as well. If you have only a couple of boxes, pick a lightweight solution like Redis.
- with persistency, you need to consider also HA. What happens if the caching layer is lost? Actually, I would say that for a cache, HA may be more important than persistency.

Finally, you need also to define the exact cache semantic you want (update behavior, invalidation behavior, cache miss management, TTL policy if any, etc ...). The 3 NoSQL engines I have listed provide some tools to help the implementation of the various strategies, but none of them will support an off-the-shelf strategy. This will require some coding to implement it.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that even though you have tried to keep factual you have now hit into the other problem with this question; it is too broad. I could put an answer here that might contradict some of yours (i.e. mentioning of caching in relation to certain techs) but neither will really help since the users question  is too broad, he needs to go off and actually test this out

Comment: Didier you are correct - I need data structures, which is why MongoDB seemed like a candidate system.  I've read several articles regarding news feed that recommend using one instance of redis to hold IDs and another to hold the objects. While this does not provide the write / updating capabilities I'm seeking, it does provide performance...

Comment: @RubenCatchmeObregon why would you use redis to store the ids? Wouldn't you then be querying two separate, potentially geographically distanced databases for essentially what you could query one for? I mean you can't just show news feed item ids to a user. It would make sense that you want the ids with the objects, on one single redis instance; if you even need redis in that equation, many people in these articles try and slap techs on for the fun of it.

Comment: Personally, I would try to keep it simple: add a caching layer if you have to, but at least make sure the caching layer is just one component and not an aggregate of several storage engines. For instance, using Redis to store both IDs and data is perfectly fine. The problems you may experience with Redis are more related to scalability and HA.

Comment: I think the problem was scalability etc why people recommended segmenting it. Neo4j does a nice job, but even so to scale out to a cluster is expensive in terms of licensing.  My feed is live right now (and cached via Neo4j) and it acts pretty much like a sql query does - returns rows of data. But even so it's costly in terms of performance, and won't do well in terms of scaling with only one server or dyno etc - would rather cache it and have my news feed process update the cached feeds in the back ground using the live feed instead of users accessing the live feed..

Comment: In other words, it's cheaper to cache the feeds than add more boxes/processing power so that Neo4j can handle the load.  Even so, while Neo4j can scale out horizontally, it only supports 6 or 12 servers max IIRC.  Throw on hundreds of thousands of users and this isn't going to do well long term.. so best to let users hit a news feed cache and let news feed updates run as some kind of background job that updates the cache when it can